# Discord.js connecting api to discord bot in an embed link

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to code a bot that will post and embed link to show the title of manga, tags, etc. based on what digits user input. The api that I'm looking at is [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nhentai-js) and I want to know what's the best way of connecting it to my discord bot?

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        let chosenNum = message.content.match(/\d+/)?.[0].slice(0);
        if (chosenNum.length > 6) {
          message.channel.send("**1-6 digits only**")
        } else{
        message.channel.send(`${chosenNum}`)
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly do you have problem with? You've already get the number from the user input. The package has a nice documentation. You can now check if the `nhentai.exists(id)` and then use `nhentai.getDoujin(id)` to get a JSON object which you can use in your embed.

Comment: Hi, sorry for not being clear. I seem to not understand hoe to get the JSON object for the embed.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you chose has a really simple API. All you need is the `nhentai.exists()` and `nhentai.getDoujin()` methods. With the first one you can check if the user submitted ID exists, and with the second one you can fetch a JSON object that you can use to populate your embed.

Check out the example below:

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const nhentai = require('nhentai-js');

const client = new Client();
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  // create an args variable that slices off the prefix and splits it into an array
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  // create a command variable by taking the first element in the array
  // and removing it from args
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'hen') {
    const chosenNum = args[0]?.match(/\d+/)?.[0];

    if (!chosenNum)
      return message.channel.send('You need to provide a number');

    if (chosenNum.length > 6)
      return message.channel.send('**1-6 digits only**');

    try {
      if (!(await nhentai.exists(chosenNum)))
        return message.channel.send(`No results found for "${chosenNum}".`);

      // res is your JSON object, feel free to console.log its content
      const res = await nhentai.getDoujin(chosenNum);
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ed2553')
        .setTitle(res.title)
        .setImage(res.pages[0])
        .setURL(res.link)
        .addField('Pages', res.details.pages[0], true)
        .addField('Uploaded', res.details.uploaded[0], true);

      if (res.details.languages)
        embed.addField('Languages', res.details.languages.join(', '), true);
      if (res.details.characters)
        embed.addField('Top characters', res.details.characters.slice(0, 3).join(', '), true);
      if (res.details.tags)
        embed.addField('Top tags', res.details.tags.slice(0, 3).join(', '), true);

      return message.channel.send(embed);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error. Maybe try again?!');
    }
  }
});
```

[image]