# Discord Js cannot read property titles of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When creating a random number generator for a discord bot I'm working on whenever someone does `+nhr` it'll either work or it'll come up with an error message in console saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'titles' of undefined

and

> Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
> promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node
> process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag

Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'nhr')) {
  //RANDOM PREFIX
  var rnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) + 1;
  if (message.channel.nsfw) {
    api.fetchDoujin(`${rnumber}`).then((doujin) => {
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ce0606')
        .setTitle(doujin.titles.pretty)
        .setURL(`https://youtube.com/${rnumber}`)
        .addFields(
          { name: 'Digits', value: `${rnumber}` },
          {
            name: 'Tags',
            value: doujin.tags.all.map((tag) => tag.name).join(', '),
          },
        )
        .setImage(doujin.cover.url)
        .setFooter('x', 'x');
      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    });
  } else {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ffc0cb')
      .setTitle('**x**')
      .setImage('x');
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
  }
}
```

(If anything else is needed within the code please comment)

Comment: Please do not fundamentally edit questions after receiving a decent answer. Especially do not edit proposed solutions into the questions code. If an answer helps but you discover more problems then please create a new question instead of changing this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using the `nhentai` npm package. The problem is you're generating a random number between 1 and 1,000,000 and the current largest ID is something a bit over 360,000. Whenever you're generating a number larger, `fetchDoujin()` resolves to `undefined` so you'll need to check if `doujin` exists.

You should always handle promise rejections. If a method can throw an error you need to catch it. Either use try/catch blocks, or after the `.then()` method add a `.catch()` method too.

It's probably a good idea to add a max number that is closer to the last ID.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'nhr')) {
  let LAST_ID = 360000;
  //RANDOM PREFIX
  let rnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * LAST_ID) + 1;
  if (message.channel.nsfw) {
    api
      .fetchDoujin(`${rnumber}`)
      .then((doujin) => {
        if (!doujin)
          return message.channel.send(`Oops, the random ID ${rnumber} is not valid...`);

        let exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#ce0606')
          .setTitle(doujin.titles.pretty)
          .setURL(`https://youtube.com/${rnumber}`)
          .addFields(
            { name: 'Digits', value: `${rnumber}` },
            {
              name: 'Tags',
              value: doujin.tags.all.map((tag) => tag.name).join(', '),
            },
          )
          .setImage(doujin.cover.url)
          .setFooter('x', 'x');
        message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error');
        console.log(err);
      });
  } else {
    let exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ffc0cb')
      .setTitle('**x**')
      .setImage('x');
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
  }
}
```

If you still want to use the `nhentai-js` library you [used in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68426722/discord-js-connecting-api-to-discord-bot-in-an-embed-link), make sure you're passing down a string to `nhentai.getDoujin()` (as numbers don't have a `.replace()` method):

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'nhr')) {
  let LAST_ID = 360000;
  let chosenNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * LAST_ID) + 1;
  if (message.channel.nsfw) {
    try {
      const res = await nhentai.getDoujin(chosenNum.toString());
      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ce0606')
        .setTitle(res.title)
        .setImage(res.pages[0])
        .setURL(res.link)
        .addField('Pages', res.details.pages[0], true)
        .addField('Uploaded', res.details.uploaded[0], true)
        .setFooter('x', 'x');

      if (res.details.languages)
        embed.addField('Languages', res.details.languages.join(', '), true);
      if (res.details.characters)
        embed.addField(
          'Top characters',
          res.details.characters.slice(0, 10).join(', '),
          true,
        );
      if (res.details.tags)
        embed.addField(
          'Top tags',
          res.details.tags.slice(0, 10).join(', '),
          true,
        );

      return message.channel.send(embed);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return message.channel.send(
        'Oops, there was an error. Maybe try again?!',
      );
    }
  } else {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ffc0cb')
      .setTitle('**x**');
    return message.channel.send(embed);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so it'll randomize a 1-6 digit strand ex. 123456

Comment: The code above does exactly that. Your problem is that there is no doujin above 366350, so whenever you generate a larger number than that, the API will return `undefined`. That's why I added a `LAST_ID` which is the largest number still available.

Comment: Okay Thanks! I set up the code with the newest version (editted above) but now I'm getting an error stating  "identifier.replace is not a function". Not sure but the bot will keep outputting "Oops, there was an error. Maybe try again?!". Do you know how to fix that? (fixed in question)

Comment: Not sure, why you've changed so many things. The suggested edit looks like something I wrote you yesterday. Did you just replace the code and changed the ID received from the user to a randomly generated one? Do you use the `nhentai-js` npm package now? It looks like the error is coming from there, not from this code.

Comment: Yeah That's what I did. I'm using the js package so that could be the reason then

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Note that an asker should not fundamentally edit a question after having received a substantial answer. I almost undid the last edit on the question, but then noticed that you have adapted your answer already. Please encourage the OP to keep this question as is and as answered by you and for any new needs create a new question. Another edit like the last one would definitly turn the question into a "moving target". You can rollback such an edit. If you do not want to let me know and I will do it for you.

Comment: @Sky Nice that you realise that.

Comment: Thanks @Yunnosch, I've rolled back the edit and I've also updated my answer. Thanks again.